# Django 1.11 upgrade creating `user_id` constraints

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am upgrading from Django 1.8 to 1.11. There are 2 migrations included in the upgrade [0007_auth](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.11/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages.py) and [0008_auth](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.11/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0008_alter_user_username_max_length.py).

For some reason 0008 is creating a bunch of MySQL foreign key constraints that didn't exist before even though when looking at the migration all that changed was the `username` max_length.

Here is an example of the query that is being run on one table that I recorded when running the migration

```
ALTER TABLE `django_admin_log` ADD CONSTRAINT 
`django_admin_log_user_id_xxxxxx_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
```

From what I can read from the 1.8 documentation these constraints should already exist on the tables that have foreign keys to the User model, as should other tables that make use of foreign keys. But my database has no `fk` constraints at all.

The reason this is a problem is because when I deploy this to production there is an `ALTER TABLE` being run on a huge table which results in the database being held (I cancelled before I could time it, but it was more than 10 minutes)

Any idea why this is happening?

And if there is a way to do it manually, or more effeciently? I can take my site down for maintenance but I'd really rather avoid it if I can instead do 20 simple manual commands.

### Update 1:

Running `manage.py sqlmigrate auth 0008` outputs:

```
ALTER TABLE `auth_user` MODIFY `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL;
```

And when MySQL does an alter table with `NOT NULL` it actually replicates the table. So I think what is happening is that the table is getting replicated and then updating the constraints on all tables that have a foreign key.

Comment: Why do you think the SQL query is from `0008` in the `auth` app?
 It looks like it's from the admin app to me. What does `manage.py showmigrations` output? You might find [`pt-online-schema-change`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) useful to avoid downtime for database migrations with MySQL.

Comment: show migrations shows 0007 and 0008 from the auth contrib.

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a link to MySQL docs that specifies that behaviour? I knew that some operations in Sqlite3 required the creation of anew table. I haven’t come across that for MySQL before.